# symfony2.1 FOQElasticaBundle class load

Tags: php, elasticsearch, symfony-2.1, elastica

I setup FOQElasticaBundle following this https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle#readme
both Elastica and FOQElasticaBundle installed using git submodule.

and when I try app/console, it gives error `The autoloader expected class "Elastica_Client" to be defined in file "/path/to/project/../vendor/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`

I found that FOQ tried to load Elastica_Client class within vendor/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php and found nothing since the class named Client.

I randomly browse elastica repo https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/v0.18.6.0/lib/Elastica/Client.php , and found that
the class previously named Elastica_Client.

the questions are

1. is FOQElasticaBundle is outdated, against the current Elastica library?
2. or is there something gone wrong with my autoload. ps: i'm using composer autoloader?

app/autoload.php

```
$loader->add('Elastica', __DIR__.'/../vendor/elastica/lib');
$loader->add('FOQ', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles');
```

Answer (score 1):

That `FOQElasticaBundle` install steps is for Symfony 2.0

In SF2.1 you have to install your bundles with composer, so just add this to your `composer.json` file:

`"ruflin/elastica": "0.19.8"`[here an example](https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle/blob/master/composer.json)

Then run this command:

`composer update`

And the last step is:

`composer dumpautoload`

The last step generate the autoloads files for you

Comment: I successfully installed FOQElasticaBundle and Elastica library, the problem is the FOQElasticaBundle unable to load Elastica classes.